# Protecting my html forms from injection

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a text box on my site that allows the use of html formatting to allow the users to make the text more presentable.

I use this code to protect most inputs to my db.

```
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
```

What i don't want it to do is remove html elements like `<p>` and `<strong>`

is there a better way to protect the inputs in text areas?

Comment: `strip_tags()` with the optional second parameter to permit `<p>, <strong>`. But this will not protect you against scripting injections via `onclick,onmouseover` etc.  http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: how do i protect against it all then?

Comment: Read the documentation and examples on `strip_tags()` linked in my previous comment. There are many user-submitted functions there to de-fang script attributes.

Comment: Cheers i didnt see the link before, but had already found my way to that site using google + stip_tags :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: @Michael You shouldn't be worried about JS injection at this point, prior to DB insertion. You handle that by encoding your output, not escaping your input. It's a completely separate problem.

Comment: @meagar I disagree in this one instance - protecting against regular XSS that is true, that it should happen at output. But in this case, since steps are already being taken to limit the permissible HTML tags, the filter should be extended to limit permissible attributes inside permissible tags before storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of defense against injections is using prepared statements.  If you use prepared statements for your queries then it really doesn't matter what the user puts into your form because you have already separated code from data.  The database will see any code that a user injects as just data rather than code.  So not only do you get the benefit of protecting yourself from injection, but your code is actually cleaner and more thought out as well.

Comment: What do u mean by a prepared statement?

Comment: You parse the query only once, and then you just re-execute it using different parameters ( values ).  Essentially, you are guaranteeing that the sql in the query never changes.  Everything that the user puts in is bound to a variable, and that variable is passed to the query prior to execution.  What this means in that any code or sql injected by a user cannot be interpreted as part of the query.  It is simply data.

Comment: Continued...Therefore if enters sql in your form, rather than just building that sql into a query string which effectively changes your query, your query remains the same and it simply searches the database for a value matching the sql, which it is unlikely to find.

You can find the basics here. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)[/link]

Answer (score 2):

I only use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when inserting data to my DB and remove Tags like `<script>` (and some others) after pulling it from the DB. I think there are a few regexes out there.

Comment: If you're removing <script> tags everytime you pull from the DB, then why not also remove them before you insert into the DB?

Comment: @CoryDanielson: because you might want to use the content in a different context.  Besides, what if you find a bug in your html sanitization algorithm.  If you do it before, when you find the bug you have to manually loop over existing content.  But if you do it after, you're fine...  Not to mention that properly escaping HTML is context dependent, so you can't do it once and done...

Comment: Apart from that, this topic we can discuss for weeks, isn't it?